# AWS CLI - Trying to copy the output of the command to text file

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, sh

I'm trying to copy the output of the Amazon S3 CLI Delete command, even if the operation is denied, but I can't seem to be able to copy the output to a text file no matter what I try to do. I'm trying to do this so I can copy all the operations that fail to a text file. Here is the command that I've been using to test:

`aws s3 rm s3://xxxxxxxxxxx --recursive >> test.txt`

```
$ aws s3 rm s3://xxxxxxxxxxx --recursive >> test.txt

delete failed: s3://xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx.png An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied
delete failed: s3://xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx.png An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied
delete failed: s3://xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx.png An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied
delete failed: s3://xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx.png An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied
delete failed: s3://xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx.png An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied
delete failed: s3://xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx.png An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied
```

When checking the test.txt, there is no new text. Would appreciate if somebody could tell me how I'm messing this command up, and how to fix it. I'm still pretty new to this and trying to understand how to use it better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly send `stderr` to file too:

`aws s3 rm s3://xxxxxxxxxxx --recursive 2>> test.txt`

To send both std output and errors:

```
aws s3 rm s3://xxxxxxxxxxx --recursive &> test.txt
# To append
aws s3 rm s3://xxxxxxxxxxx --recursive >> test.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: Reader beware: `&>` is a non-standard device that is not recognized by all shells.  Indeed, it violates the shell standard, and a shell ought to treat it as `cmd &` followed by the simple command `> test.txt`.  In bash, it is equivalent to the construction `> test.txt 2>&1`